# PHP is looking for php.ini in C:\php rather than C:\Windows

Tags: php, iis, windows-server-2012-r2, fastcgi

My monitoring software (Dynatrace) messed up php on my web servers. For some reason all of my IIS websites are loading the php.ini file from C:\php-5.4 instead of C:\Windows.

**From phpinfo():**

- Configuration File (php.ini) Path: C:\Windows
- Loaded Configuration File: C:\php-5.4\php.ini

I'm not sure what Dynatrace did to cause this but even after uninstalling it I can't get php to reference the preferred path. I know Dynatrace is the culprit because when I restored my server from a previous date, the issue returned within hour. I restored it again and immediately uninstalled Dynatrace - the change never happened. I still have some servers that I did not restore, so they're still loading the php.ini file from C:\php-5.4

I've tried reinstalling php (go-pear) and confirmed the [directories are correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TIr3c.png)

This code was added to my php.ini file;

```
;***** Added by go-pear
include_path=".;C:\php-5.4\pear"
;*****
```

FastCGI is configured correctly, it's looking for the executable in C:\php-5.4

There are no PHP registry entries on my servers as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28351548/how-to-set-php-ini-location)

I can't figure out how to change where the php.ini file is being loaded from. Any ideas?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php According to the docs, directory of PHP takes precedence over Windows directory.

Comment: Why the sudden change? Every implementation guide I find typically references C:\Windows

How do I differentiate? I read that keeping php.ini in your C:\php-<ver> folder is bad practice - it's more work when it comes time to upgrade.

Comment: Sudden change? It has been changed for years. And what you heard about can be out-of-date.

Comment: Sudden change to my environment. 

As I said, when you install php for FastCGI it automatically references C:\Windows. Something is suddenly overloading that path and Dynatrace initiated it.

Comment: This affected over a dozen web servers, 80 websites at the same time. Dynatrace team thinks it was PHP injection causing corruption, but that still doesn't tell me how to correct it.

Comment: That’s possible if the php.ini file was not yours. You are using an ancient release (5.4) which makes no surprise. To really create a secure environment, build new servers with all supported software pieces and then there can be some meaningful discussion beyond.

Comment: Easy to say from your seat. This version of php is required for the vendor software I support. The environment is configured according to the requirements.

Why can no one tell me how to tell php where to look for the php.ini file? This is such a simple question, the solution shouldn't take 3 days of scouring the internet.

Comment: “Why can no one tell me how to tell php where to look for the php.ini file?” I provided the official link in the very first comment.

Comment: I did try everything in that list before but I missed the part about the PHPRC environment variable. After adding that PHP is finally looking in C:\Windows for the php.ini file. What really bugs me is I still don't know what happened to cause PHP to look for php.ini in the working directory (C:\php-5.4). The article itself says that PHP will not look in the working directory for CLI. There are no registry entries for PHP either.

Comment: So the true problem is that that link can be misinterpreted. The page starts with "php.ini is searched for in these locations (in order):", which means if php.ini exists in the directory of PHP (C:\php-5.4 in your case), PHP will use it and won't read Windows directory. I said above and that's called precedence. If you, however, want the php.ini file in Windows directory to take effect, then any item with higher precedence (like setting PHPRC, or adding registry keys) can be utilized. That answers what happened when you set PHPRC. Hope you can fully understand that page soon.